# Unzip with Powershell doesn't work on XP

Tags: powershell, zip, unzip

I got the Request to unzip a .zip file with Powershell. On the Internet i found the following code multiple times:

```
    param(  [String]$newlocation, [String]$filepath)
    if(($newlocation -and $filepath) -and ((test-path $newlocation) -and (test-path $filepath)))
    {
       Copy-Item $filepath $newlocation
       $shell_app=new-object -com shell.application
       $filename = $filepath.split("\")[-1]
       if(Test-Path "$newlocation\$filename")
       {
           $zip_file = $shell_app.namespace("$newlocation\$filename")
           $destination = $shell_app.namespace($newlocation)
           $destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items())
       }
    }
```

As I implemented it into my script it changed a little bit. This above is the changed version. Now I've got an error:

```
Exception calling "NameSpace" with "1" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT
: 0x80070002)"
At Z:\MyScripts\deploy.ps1:34 char:34
+     $zip_file = $shell_app.namespace <<<< ("$newlocation\$filename")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

And then another one, that is quite clear (caused by the first error

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At Z:\MyScripts\deploy.ps1:36 char:39
+     $destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items <<<< ())
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (items:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The File and the destination Path both exist and I've got rights to acces them (I created both). I'm running on Windows XP with PowerShell 2.0

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

Here is my entire dump from Powershell when I run it directly on the console.
[image: PowershellError]

I hope you guys can help me or at least tell me where I can go to find an answer.

I tried already to unzip the zip file manually and it worked, I have got access to both, the file and the file path (as I created both).

Comment: You have the code *$filepath.split("\")[-1]* but I can't see where filepath is assigned - it appears you are splitting something which has no value (or is null).

Comment: Just to note scripting questions belong *here*. Whoever voted to migrate obviously did not read the question properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found this one on the web:

Also the code looks to me like it's dependent on the Windows Explorer support for zipFolders, which you may have turned off

```
Unregister (disable) XP Zip folders
REGSVR32 /u C:\Windows\System32\zipfldr.dll

Register (enable) XP Zip folders
REGSVR32 zipfldr.dll
```

It's from [here](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1433).

I came to it during testing my script on several machines, e.g. on a Windows Server 2008 and on a Windows 7 client. Both worked, so I came to the conclusion that it's not my script,but it's my PC. After the registration of XP Zip folders, it worked.

Many thanks to the guy who wrote this one, I dumped too much time into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into a problem with accessing the COM objects. If you are using 64-bit windows, make sure you execute your script from a 64-bit powershell.exe. This means the powershell.exe in c:\windows\system32...\v1.0.... This was counter-intuitive for me, having the '32' in system32. I was executing powershell from Console2, which was a 32bit process, and was therefore launching 32-bit powershell (from c:\windows\syswow64...). Also make sure your powershell.exe is being run with administrator privileges.

Comment: Thx for the information, but my machine is 32 Bit. I check that with the admin rights.

Comment: Try ConEmu? http://superuser.com/a/446320/139371 There is no problem with running 64bit apps from 32bit gui. And you may mix normal and elevated tabs in one window.

Comment: I'm not using normal and elevated tabs in one window, additinaly my powershell is running in 32 Bit too (like everything on my pc)

Comment: @Maximus, thanks! I've been looking for ConEmu. I read about it a while ago but couldn't remember what it was called.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to automate the Windows Shell, now in .NET Framework 4.5 there is a *ZipFile* class that you can use like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($sourceFile, $targetFolder)
```

**Edit:** Oops, .NET Framework 4.5 is *not supported on Windows XP*.
Anyhow, this answer might still prove useful for anyone else with ZIP problems in Powershell…